# Order of ordinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

I'm reading Kuratowski's "Set theory", and following the next definition from the Chapter 7:

"An order number $\alpha$ is less than $\gamma$ iff some $\alpha$-set is isomorphic to an initial segment of some $\gamma$-set." Now, it's intuitively clear that if some $\alpha$-set is a subset of $\gamma$-set, then $\alpha \leq \gamma$. But how can I prove it using the definition?

Comment: Let $A$ be the $\alpha$-set and $B$ the $\gamma$-set. If $A=B$, the inclusion is an order isomorphism and $\alpha=\beta$. Assume $A$ is a proper subset of $B$. Then the set of elements of $B$ that are not in $A$ is non-empty. Let $b_0$ the first element of $B\setminus A$. If there aren't elements of $A$ greater than $b_0$, then $A$ is an initial segment of $B$ and $\alpha\leq \gamma$. If there are elements of $A$ that are larger than $b_0$, then let $a_0$ be the first of those elements. Send $a_0$ to $b_0$. Observe that all elements of $B$ that are smaller than $b_0$ are elements of $A$ ...

Comment: ... map those to themselves. Now continue by transfinite induction. Assume that all elements of $B$ smaller than $b$ have some element of $A$ mapped to them. If $b\in A$, then map it to itself. If there are no elements of $A$ larger than $b$, then we are done and $A$ is already mapped to an initial segment of $B$. Otherwise, let $a$ be the smallest element of $A$ that is larger than $b$. Map $a$ to $b$. By the induction all elements of $A$ are mapped to some element of $B$. By construction this map is injective and its image is an initial segment of $B$.